# Dynamodb - batchWrite not working(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using lambda, API gateway and dynamodb

I am creating a batchWrite function to upload more than 25 items in one single function.

But I find that when I upload 35 items,
the first 25 items are uploaded successfully to dynamodb, but last 10 items fail but no error is logged.

The function is written in node.js

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sha1 = require('sha1');
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {

    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;

    const { excelObject } = JSON.parse(event.body);

    if(excelObject){
        await uploadFileByBatch(excelObject)
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "access-control-allow-origin": "*"
        },
        body: responseBody
    }

    console.log(response)
    return response
}

let uploadFileByBatch = async function (payload) {

    var items = [];
    var params={};

    if(payload.length > 25){
        console.log("> 25")
        let newObj = payload.slice(0,25)
        payload.splice(0,25)

        console.log("new Payload length")
        console.log(payload.length)

        newObj.forEach(obj =>{
            let hash = sha1(Buffer.from(new Date().toString()+ Math.random()));
            items.push(
                {
                    PutRequest:{
                        Item: {
                            id: obj.id?obj.id:hash,
                            organization_EN: obj.organization_EN,
                            email: obj.email,
                            isActive: obj.isActive
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        })

        params = {
            RequestItems:{
                "Community": items
            }
        }
        console.log(params)
        try{
            const data = await documentClient.batchWrite(params).promise();
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        uploadFileByBatch(payload)
    }else{
        console.log("less than 25")
        payload.forEach(obj =>{
            let hash = sha1(Buffer.from(new Date().toString()+ Math.random()));
            items.push(
                {
                    PutRequest:{
                        Item: {
                            id: obj.id?obj.id:hash,
                            organization_EN: obj.organization_EN,
                            email: obj.email,
                            isActive: obj.isActive
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        })
        params = {
            RequestItems:{
                "Community": items
            }
        }
        console.log(params)
        try{
            console.log("first BatchWrite")
            const data = await documentClient.batchWrite(params).promise();
            console.log("first Data")
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

}
```

The log is like below.

```
>25
New Payload length
10

{
  RequestItems: {
    'Community': [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  }
}

first BatchWrite
Less than 25
{
  RequestItems: {
    'Community': [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  }
}

{
  statusCode: 0,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
  },
  body: ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload more than 25 in a single request for batchWrite function with DynamoDB

> If one or more of the following is true, DynamoDB rejects the entire batch write operation:
>
> - One or more tables specified in the BatchWriteItem request does not exist.
> - Primary key attributes specified on an item in the request do not match those in the corresponding table's primary key schema.
> - You try to perform multiple operations on the same item in the same BatchWriteItem request. For example, you cannot put and delete the same item in the same BatchWriteItem request.
> - Your request contains at least two items with identical hash and range keys (which essentially is two put operations).
> - There are more than 25 requests in the batch.
> - Any individual item in a batch exceeds 400 KB.
> - The total request size exceeds 16 MB.

You can retrieve informations about this here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

There are ways to handle big batch operations, you can maybe do parallels requests of 25, but you should be careful with it.

Comment: I divide the 35 item into 2 batch to upload, so it is not ok too?

Comment: Yes it is, usually i prefer doing 25 then 25 then 25 etc.. than doing parallel. Because let's say a parallel one crash, you can't really retry where you were at. If you are doing one after another when it crashes you can retry with the id tha fails

Comment: So if i upload 100 items, I can send 4 requests in frontend instead. Is it what u mean?

Comment: Yes. This way if one a batch fail, you can start the process again from the one that fails. To try again (with updated data or not)